# MySQL Date_Format isn't working with

Tags: php, mysql, time, mysqli, date-format

I have a PHP page with a MySQL database with 2 fields that use the `TIME` type in MySQL. I want to convert those two fields from the 24 hour format `(00:00:00)` into 12 hour AM/PM format `(00:00 AM)` using MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT('','')` but it's not working.

So far, what I have done is created a 3rd and 4th field that also uses the TIME type. I send the 1st and 2nd field into the 3rd and 4th and convert the 3rd and 4th to preserve the original.

```
<?php
//connection statements omitted

$sql="SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY date LIMIT $start, $amount";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

//Sends the original time_in data to the new format_in column. 
$sql2="UPDATE $table SET format_in = time_in";
$result2=$mysqli->query($sql2);

$sql3="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%l:%i %p') FROM $table";
$result3=$mysqli->query($sql3);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

?>
//other fields omitted
<td><?php echo $row['format_in'];?></td>

//end while loop
<?php } ?>
```

The only thing this code does is replicates whatever was in the time_in column. Which is the standard 24 hour format `00:00:00`. Basically, this code doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong here?

EDITED to show my    $result

Comment: Format `TIME` types with `TIME_FORMAT()`.  Please also show us small code which reproduces the issue — the current snippet cannot be what you're looking at (`$result2` is not `$result3` is not `$result`...)

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = $result3->fetch_array()){
```

instead of

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
```

Based on the conversation we had in comments section:

Change

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY date LIMIT $start, $amount";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT field_1,field_2,field_n,DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%l:%i %p') format_in FROM $table ORDER BY date LIMIT $start, $amount";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: That will just mess up all of my other fields. I want the rest of my columns to work as well as the new format_in column. Do I need to somehow change my querys? I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: I dont understand. You do not have a `$result` variable in your code, so how will the loop work?. `$row` does not fetch anything from `$result3`, so how will you get to show the formatted date if there is nothing that accesses it?

Comment: I edited it to add in the code. Didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: Ok, `<?php echo $row['format_in'];?>` will never print the **formatted** `format_in` value because it is getting it from the `select *..` query. What you will need to do is change the select * query to specify each field name AND `DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%l:%i %p')` instead of `*`

Comment: I'm getting an undefined index error with format_in. Used the exact same code as above. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have made an update in my answer. Basically in the query,  change `..field_n, DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%l:%i %p') FROM $table` to ``..field_n, DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%l:%i %p') format_in FROM $table`. Notice the additional *format_in* after `..'%l:%i %p')`

Comment: Just tried it, it got rid of the error but the format isn't right (still 00:00:00). I think I know how to fix that. Going to try it now.

Comment: Yeah I'm stumped. Can't get the format to change. I'm done for the day will be back again tomorrow morning. Thanks for the help Raidenace.

Comment: A'right! Let me know how it goes tomorrow, cause Im just curious to know what you changed

Comment: I gave up. In the end I realized the end user would need to put the time into a field using 24 hour format which doesn't help me. I want the user to put in a 12 hour format and have it display as a 12 hour format.

Comment: hmm..seems more like front end validation then? Force the user to enter in the format you need..

Comment: Yes that's what I realized today. Worst case scenario is that the end user has to learn how to use the 24 hour format for the website.

Comment: You can add JS validation and alerts that will tell the end user if he enters wrong. However having said that, I have been able to use date_format without issues for ages. Something might be amiss. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: OK so I finally got something working. I ended up just starting on a completely fresh page with no code and realized that the problem was improper syntax for the date_format. I needed to do SELECT date_format(format_in,'%r') AS format_in, time_in, time_out FROM $table";

Comment: strange..`DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%l:%i %p') ` supposed to work too..did you try that in new completely fresh page?

Comment: No it wasn't the `DATE_FORMAT(,)` that was wrong, it was what came after. All we needed to do was put `AS` after the statement like:  `DATE_FORMAT(format_in,'%r') AS format_in`.

Comment: shit!! have been working with oracle for so long! I didnt realize mysql needed `AS`!